# Linear Algebra: Linear functional, proof writing, linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Let $E$ be a finite dimensional vector space. Prove that if $L \subseteq E$ is a linearly independent subset of $E$, there exists a basis $X \subseteq E$ of $E$ with $L \subseteq X$.

---

Below is my proof. It feels skimpy: I am unsure about the final step: "...since $span X$ is the smallest subspace containing $X$, $L \subset X$." Am I right to be skeptical? Why or why not? Is there another way to do this?

---

Proof

Let $L$ be a linearly independent subset of $E$.

If $\dim L = \dim E$, then $L$ is a basis of $E$, and $L \subseteq L$, so we would be done.

If $\dim L \leq \dim E$, then $L$ does not span $E$.

But every finite dimensional vector space has a basis. Let this basis be $X$. By definition, $\operatorname{span}X = E$, so $\operatorname{span} L \subset \operatorname{span} X$, and since $\operatorname{span} L$ is the smallest subspace containing $L$, $L \subset \operatorname{span} X$, and since $\operatorname{span} X$ is the smallest subspace containing $X$, $L \subset X$, and we are done.

Comment: You can't say that L lies in X just because L lies in span X. Consider X = {(1,0,0), (0,1,0),(0,0,1)} and L = {(1,1,0),(2,3,0)}. L certainly lies in span X but does not lie in X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In what you have written, you say that we can find an $X$ that is a basis for $E$, but we cannot conclude from this that every vector in $L$ is an element of $X$.

Instead, make use of the theorem that if $L$ is a linearly independent set of vectors and $\textrm{span}(L) \neq E$, then we can find a vector $v$ such that $\{ v \} \cup L$ is a linearly independent set.

Your proof can then proceed by induction in $k$, where $k = \textrm{dim}(X) - \textrm{dim}(L)$.